# Can I install Age of Empires on a MacBook?

Tags: macos

Is it possible to install Age of Empires on a MacBook? If so, could you give me any pointers to do so: where to download, whether it's free, and how to install?

Comment: You buy it, then follow the instructions. If you want to buy it online, search engines like google allow you to find vendors.

Answer (score 2):

You can install Age of Empires for Windows versions 1, 2, or 3 inside of a [Wineskin wrapper](https://www.paulthetall.com/age-of-empires-2-mac/). Alternatively you can [install Windows using Boot Camp](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT201468) and run it natively. You can also play the Mac version (see SleepingGod's answer), but you may have to use a Classic Mac OS emulator such as [SheepShaver](http://sheepshaver.cebix.net/). Any of these options require purchasing a CD for the version that you want to play.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, it is possible for you to install and play Age of Empires on a Macbook. A company called *[Macsoft](http://macsoftgames.com/)* built a mac version in the late 2000's but have since been aquired by Destineer and have more or less stopped producing anything. AOE2 and AOE3 disks can still be bought at retailers (e.g [Amazon](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Age-Of-Empires-III-Mac/dp/B000HZRLIM)). If you already have existing windows software and your like to run it on your Mac: you may need an *windows emulator for mac* such as Bootcamp or use a program like [Winebottler](http://winebottler.kronenberg.org/)

Answer (score -2):

A method that is guaranteed to work is by installing Windows on your Mac using [Bootcamp](https://support.apple.com/en-nz/HT201468)

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.